# How to make iPad ask receipt printer printout without framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, printing

now i got one receipt printer model xp900 (from XPrinter china). Anyone hear about this receipt printer ? Is it printable through iOS device without any framework ? i have success print out through (Star, Asterix) receipt printer. But only this 1, i cannot find any solution. Anyone can help on this ?

Comment: Does it support Bluetooth Low Energy or WiFi?

Comment: that printer support wifi